# Android: блокировка кнопки до момента заполнения полей

Tags: ui, android, java, instagram

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом сделали разработчики `Instagram'a` блокировку кнопки входа до момента заполнения полей?

[image]

Comment: проверкой EditText на пустоту

Comment: `if(editText.getText().length() > 0)
   button.setEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, плохо загуглил.

[`In Android, how to make Login button disable with respect to EditText?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002963/in-android-how-to-make-login-button-disable-with-respect-to-edittext)